# How to always kill dired buffer when deleting a folder?

Tags: buffers, dired

If I'm in dired and have a subfolder with another dired buffer (a common situation when navigating up/down directory) and want to delete a folder, I hit `Dx` to mark for deletion, then execute.

Emacs then asks if I want to trash the folder. I confirm, then it asks if I want to kill the dired buffer of the folder as well.

I can't think of a situation where I'd like to trash the folder but keep the buffer. Is there a way to always trash the buffer when trashing the folder?

Comment: A Dired buffer does not always correspond to a particular folder. A Dired buffer can contain any number of folders and files, from any part(s) of the file system. Presumably your question applies only when a Dired buffer maps one-to-one to a single folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is for safety. since it can be surprising if Emacs deletes an ordinary buffer without asking user. You can file a bug report if you want to. Meanwhile you can always advice `y-or-n-p` to do what you want.

```el
(define-advice dired-clean-up-after-deletion
    (:around (old-fun &rest r) kill-dired-buffer-quietly)
  (define-advice y-or-n-p (:around (old-fun prompt) just-yes)
    (if (string-prefix-p "Kill Dired buffer" prompt)
        t
      (funcall old-fun prompt)))
  (unwind-protect (apply old-fun r)
    (advice-remove 'y-or-n-p #'y-or-n-p@just-yes)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following snippet in your init file:

```
(eval-after-load  'dired                                                                                                               
  '(defun dired-clean-up-after-deletion (fn)
     "My. Clean up after a deleted file or directory FN.                                                                               
Remove expanded subdir of deleted dir, if any."
     (save-excursion (and (cdr dired-subdir-alist)
                          (dired-goto-subdir fn)
                          (dired-kill-subdir)))

     ;; Offer to kill buffer of deleted file FN.                                                                                       
     (if dired-clean-up-buffers-too
         (progn
           (let ((buf (get-file-buffer fn)))
             (and buf
                  (save-excursion ; you never know where kill-buffer leaves you                                                        
                    (kill-buffer buf))))
           (let ((buf-list (dired-buffers-for-dir (expand-file-name fn)))
                 (buf nil))
             (and buf-list
                  (while buf-list
                    (save-excursion (kill-buffer (car buf-list)))
                    (setq buf-list (cdr buf-list)))))))
     ;; Anything else?                                                                                                                 
     ))
```

Courtesy of [pmielke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11567921/4055832)

You may also want to browse this Emacs wiki page about [buffer reuse in Dired](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredReuseDirectoryBuffer)